# broken dnf while updating fedora 34 to 35

Tags: linux, fedora, upgrade, dnf

I'm using fedora 34. Update to 35 returns error
After some search with google, the issue is reported to be a broken dnf.
Tried to solve issue with no success.
error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dnf", line 57, in <module>
    from dnf.cli import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dnf/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    import dnf.base
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 29, in <module>
    import libdnf.transaction
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/libdnf/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import conf
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/libdnf/conf.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import _conf
ImportError: /usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/libdnf/_conf.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6libdnf10ConfigRepo14failovermethodB5cxx11Ev
```

Comment: So users don't suggest what you have already tried, what have you tried?  What command generated the Traceback?

Comment: #dnf update 
and the result is shown above in the first post

Comment: is anything not "normal" in the output of `rpm -q -s libdnf`?

Comment: There is nothing abnormal. 
I mean the output is normal. 
a peace of the result under my comment. 

normal        /usr/lib/.build-id
normal        /usr/lib/.build-id/1d
normal        /usr/lib/.build-id/1d/c02cc33645774f095b2ce0b2636267191e76a3
normal        /usr/lib64/libdnf

Comment: And also for `rpm -q -s python3-libdnf`?

Comment: What is the output of `uname -r`?

Comment: Thanks for your help. 
I think that the issue is solved. I will document it and share it with you how I did solve it. 
Thanks it's solve.